# Python pyodbc Unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, odbc, pyodbc

I have a string variable res which I have derived from a pyodbc cursor as shown in the bottom.
The table `test` has a single row with data `ä` whose unicode codepoint is `u'\xe4'`.

The Result I get is

```
>>> res,type(res)
('\xe4', <type 'str'>)
```

Whereas the result I should have got is.

```
>>> res,type(res)
(u'\xe4', <type 'unicode'>)
```

I tried adding charset as utf-8 to my pyodbc connect string as shown below.
The result was now correctly set as a unicode but the codepoint was for someother string `꓃` which could be due to a possible bug in the pyodbc driver.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='datbase;charset=utf8',ansi=True,autocommit=True)
>>> res,type(res)
(u'\ua4c3', <type 'unicode'>)
```

Actual code

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling=False
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='datbase',ansi=True,autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cur = cursor.execute('SELECT col1 from test')
res = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
print(res)
```

Additional details
Database: Teradata
pyodbc version: 2.7

So How do I now either

1) cast `('\xe4', <type 'str'>)` to `(u'\xe4', <type 'unicode'>)` (is it possible to do this without unintentional side-effects?)

2) resolve the pyodbc/unixodbc issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something I think is best handled with Python, instead of fiddling with [pyodbc.connect](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module) arguments and driver-specific connection string attributes.

`'\xe4'` is a [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) encoded string representing the unicode [ä](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/228) character.

To explicitly decode the pyodbc result in Python 2.7:

```
>>> res = '\xe4'
>>> res.decode('latin1'), type(res.decode('latin1'))
(u'\xe4', <type 'unicode'>)
>>> print res.decode('latin1')
ä
```

Python 3.x does this for you (the [`str` type includes unicode characters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)):

```
>>> res = '\xe4'
>>> res, type(res)
('ä', <class 'str'>)
>>> print(res)
ä
```

Comment: Thanks it works as expected. however our requirement is to support Asian characters too, so I am going with JayDeBeApi which uses JDBC via jpype.

Comment: This approach is discouraged. "Fiddling" with connection parameters is the native way and should be used as described in @Ferrarezi's answer.

Answer (score 13):

For Python 3, try this:

After `conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='datbase',ansi=True,autocommit=True)`

Place this:

`conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf8')
conn.setencoding(encoding='utf8')`

or

`conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='iso-8859-1')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='iso-8859-1')
conn.setencoding(encoding='iso-8859-1')`

etc...

Python 2:

`cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(str, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(unicode, encoding='utf-8')`

etc...

`cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='encode-foo-bar')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='encode-foo-bar')
cnxn.setencoding(str, encoding='encode-foo-bar')
cnxn.setencoding(unicode, encoding='encode-foo-bar')`

Comment: Thanks for posting an update relevant to current versions of pyodbc (4.x and up). More details are available at the [pyodbc Wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#teradata).

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful for me using Python3 and MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver on MacOS.

Comment: I am also a Mac user and faed the same problem, this solution helped me.